# Unit Testing AppEngine for failures

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nose

For our current GAE app, we have add quite a lot of unit tests around our code. But we have only be able to test the positive side of things when it comes to testing GAE services. For instance, we want to test that if a put() in a model fails, we handle that error or exception correctly. Same goes for EmailMessage().send() and so on.

So the question is: with GAE testbed can you force a failure of one of their services for unit testing purposes?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a testbed that will allow you to test failures - but you could try using [mocks](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to simulate the failures and test that way.